Drive a load through with variable current with sequential operation of MOSFET ? is it possible?
Want to heat the nichrome wire for 600ms with high current and then to lower the current for rest of the time ; so I am using 2 MOSFEts driven through ESP32 and sequential operation of the MOSFETs with desired time limit edited in the firmware. But in load and the source to drain connection are facing some issues. Even the first MOSFET is off there is still current flowing the MOSFET 1, which I don't want. Suggest any idea to resolve the connections.

Hello and welcome.  It would really help if you added a circuit diagram so we know exactly the problem you're describing.  And exactly the mosfets you're using.

Can't answer this question without knowing if the MOSFETs are P-channel or N-channel, and how they are connected to the supplies and load, and what those supplies are. We require a schematic.

We can only guess with no schematic. However, the usual technique would be to use PWM which the ESP32 has no problem generating and requires only one MOSFET.

I was doing with it two  N-MOS module; (https://protosupplies.com/product/high-power-dual-mosfet-switch-module/)  driving it through GPIO pin 5 and 18 and connecting two SMPS at different power supply(12v and 31v) to Vin (+ve and -ve )terminal of two MOSFET).and shorting the Vout (+ve & -ve ) of both mosfet and then to vout to load. But i know this dumb move . So i switched to Solid state relay and it worked but i want to to it with the Mosfet to compact the size. Refer your idea if you have something.
